# NetLogo - How to read and store data from GIS raster in a dictionary or two parallel list?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am  new to Netlogo and I am struggling with the following problem with the implementation of a model for opinion dynamics in a spatial context.
I imported a GIS raster with four different landuse classes (value 1-4) with the following code:

```
to loadData                                                                                    
    clear-patches
    initLandCharacter
      show "loading landCharacter from file luw6604.asc"
      set landUse gis:load-dataset landUseDataSet
      show word "rows : "gis:height-of landUse
      show word "columns: "gis:width-of landUse
      gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of landUse
      gis:apply-raster landUse value
      resize-world 0 gis:width-of landUse (gis:height-of landUse - ( 2 * gis:height-of landUse)) 0
```

In my model 3 static breeds of people shall have different opinons on every patch in the world based on the landuse-value at certain pxcor pycor and the distance between this patch and their own location.

Therefore, my idea is to create either a dictionary or parallel lists to store keys for location as well as the corresponding opinions.

However, after trying for days, I am more confused than in the beginng and I feel entirely lost.
Please, If someone has any ideas, how to solve this problem. I would be very grateful

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, what do you want to store ? You can defined `varX` and `varX` variables and get the results in the behavior space or, defined `varX` and `varY` as 2 lists and record for each ticks the pxcor pycor whit `lput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan, it sounds as if the GIS data is not essential to your question.  Is the following correct? You want to store a value--an opinion--for each pair [patch, person].  This opinion is a function of two things: The breed of the person, and the person's distance to the patch.  Here are some thoughts that occur to me.  Some of the following may be useful.

I see a few natural ways to store this information:

1. Store opinions in people.
2. Store opinions in patches.
3. Store opinions both ways.  This requires some care.
4. Store opinions in a separate data structure you can access using a patch, person pair.
5. Create a separate breed of turtles called `opinions`.  (This is probably not going to be what you want.)

Whether 1, 2, or 3 is most useful depends on what the rest of the program needs to do.  For example, if my program was going to mainly operate on people, it might be most convenient to store opinions in people.  Then I could access the opinions for each person using `ask people [...]`, for example.

Another factor is this:

If you store opinions in people, then within each person, there will be a data structure containing opinions that you have to be able to access via `pxcor`s and `pycor`s.  This could be a list of lists, or you could use one of the two-dimensional data structures that NetLogo offers via extensions: array, table, and matrix.

If you store opinions in patches, you might be able to store them in a list, but you would have to have a way of finding the right element of the list.  Perhaps each person could have a special index number that indicates which element of each patch's opinion list is the one corresponding to that person.

If you use option 4, you might need to create a 3-dimensional data structure (`pxcor`, `pycor`, and person).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advise Mars and Seth.

I made it finally work using the following approach...

I installed a counter in the setup for patches to assign an id to each patch:

let counter 0 
set counter counter + 1 
set id counter

Than I calculated an initial-opinion for each turtle per patch by using the distance. Here the code for the test model:

let op 0
let dummy patches with [value > 0]
ask turtles[
  let tx xcor
  let ty ycor
  show "##############################################"
  ask dummy[
    let dist distancexy tx ty
    show id
    show value
    show dist 
    if dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]
       if dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]
          if dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]
             if dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]

```
if dist > ? and dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?] 
   if dist > ? and dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]
      if dist > ? and dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]
         if dist > ? and dist < ? and value = ? [set op ?]

if dist > ? and value = ? [set op ?]
   if dist > ? and value = ? [set op ?]
      if dist > ? and value = ? [set op ?]
         if dist > ? and value = 4 [set op ?]
show op
```

]
 ]

The result is a sequence that gives the an patch id and an opinion based on distance and patch-value. as well as the calculated distances between all turtle and patches.